# How to restart computer with PowerShell console open

Tags: powershell

Within PowerShell 2.0 running in Windows XP, I execute the following command:

```
Restart-Computer
```

And get the following message:

> Windows cannot end this program.  It may need more time to complete an operation.
>
> To return to Windows and check the status of the program, click Cancel.
>
> If you choose to end the program immediately, you will lose any unsaved data.  To end the program now, click End Now.

This happens whether I restart from PowerShell or from Windows itself.  Any idea how I can restart a computer that will close a PowerShell console without prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-Force` to cause an immediate restart of the computer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `shutdown.exe` with the `-f` parameter. Run `shutdown /?` from a cmd window for the full details.